# Make VIM reload file as soon as it changes on disk

Tags: vim

I don't want to have to keep reloaded a log file manually, I want to automatically see my logs as they come in.

Apparently, VIM has this feature built in, something called autoread, but I can't get it to work in Ubuntu

I can run

```
sudo vi ~/.vimrc
```

to edit vim's config file like so:

```
 set number
 set autoread
```

The number argument works perfectly. autoread doesn't work at all.

Any ideas or hacks? I want VIM to automatically scroll the bottom of the file when a file it's viewing is updated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `tail` command does exactly what I want...does it a little better actually:

```
tail /var/logs/foo.log
```

That will automatically print of `foo.log` to the console, and, when `foo.log` is updated, this will be reflected in the console.

Answer (score -1):

I found that autoread works, but the refresh only happens when I bring the window into focus (for my setup, moving the mouse out of the window, then back into it).